# How to get rid of fog / odor in a bathroom without windows or an extractor fan?

Tags: bathroom, ventilation, fans

The previous owners decided to cheap out and leave our suite bathroom with passive ventilation. There doesn't appear to be any wiring either, so adding a circuit would cost a lot of money and is a down-the-road problem. In the mean time I was wondering if a small fan would make any noticeable difference when the room fogs up. I have a 120mm PC case fan, smart plug, and battery-powered air quality monitor that detects humidity. Was thinking of rigging these three things together to create a short-term solution. But before I put any effort into it, I was wondering if this would even work? Thank you.

Comment: The moisture has to go *somewhere*. Just moving it around the bathroom, or transferring it into another room, likely would do more harm than good. "There doesn't appear to be any wiring either," is a bit vague. Is there *no* electric outlet or light in the bathroom? If there is, you could run a dehumidifier as a temporary help -- but they use a lot of electricity.

Comment: Location of the room in the house/building?  Any windows/lights?  Adding a circuit is most of the time a PITA more than costing money, if you do it yourself.  At worst using a fan with an extension cord pushing the air out an window should work for a time(not number one idea).

Comment: There is an intake an exhaust vent, but the exhaust vent has no wiring. There's no receptacle on that side of the bathroom, but there is on the other side. There's also a door separating that the light switch and light, so I'm thinking the electrician would have to run power from a receptacle on the other side of the wall (the bedroom).

Dehumidifier would probably work, but that would probably take up a lot of space.

Comment: If there is a light there is power.  Does the vent have a fan to push/pull air out?  Minimum have an LED light left on to power the fan.

Comment: One approach is to put the fan **inline** elsewhere along the vent, or even outside the building at the vent exit, where it's (perhaps) more convenient to wire it. Either is also virtually always quieter than a fan in the bathroom itself.

Comment: @crip659 The bathroom is located in the middle of the house, so no windows unfortunately. Adding a circuit would be the obvious solution, but won't be able to get there today or even this month. The floor vent pushes air in and the passive vent just lets air flow into it. It does eventually clear the bathroom, but it could take hours –especially if the HVAC isn't on.

There is a light... on the other side of the door. So running power that way would require going through multiple studs.

Comment: @Ecnerwal This would probably be the best long-term solution actually. I could probably rig that up in my crawl space once I figure out which vent goes where. Thank you.

Comment: "It does eventually clear the bathroom, but it could take hours –especially if the HVAC isn't on." Get a smart-stat and set the stir setting to 20m~30m per hour; not 5m. If it has an ECM, that's what it should be anyway. - Otherwise; box fans and extension cords, ... and then you can more evenly rot your house from the inside.

Comment: Back in the day, I used to use a "portable" dehumidifier plugged into an outlet controlled by a timer switch.  The unit was about 18" tall and maybe 8" deep, and easily fit on top of the (surface mount) medicine cabinet.  Nowadays I'd probably use some kind of smart switch or smart outlet.  I did eventually upgrade the vent fan and it was easily able to handle the moisture in the BA.

Answer (score 3):

Bathrooms are **required** by the International Residential Code (IRC) to either have an operable window or an exhaust fan.

If you have a window, use it! That is the easiest solution. If the ventilation from just opening the window doesn't get rid of humidity/odors fast enough, or if the heat in the summer or cold in the winter is a problem, put a fan *in the window*. Sort of like a room air conditioner, but much smaller and a lot less energy. *Based on comments, no window, but leaving this in because it could help others in similar situations.*

An exhaust fan does *not* need a lot of power. A quick search shows plenty in the 20W - 30W range. So there should be no problem whatsoever piggybacking one onto your existing lighting circuit. You do **not** need a new circuit. There are two things you need for an exhaust fan:

- Electricity

This is the easy part. Easiest is to either replace an existing ceiling light fixture or splice into the wires (all splices must be inside a junction box, normally with wire nuts inside either the light fixture or fan) and mount near the existing light fixture. The catch is that this will *usually* require having the fan on whenever the light is on.

The better method is to run a separate cable from a switch to the fan, or a cable with two separate switched hots for light and fan from a double-switch. These possibilities are not that hard to do, but do require more work than a simple "fan/light in place of light with existing switch" setup.

- Venting of the Exhausted Air

This is usually the hard part. Since you don't have a window, you need to run ductwork either up to the roof (easy if this is the top regular floor and you have an accessible attic) or sideways (i.e., over other rooms and out the side of the house). Do **NOT** vent into an attic or inter-floor space - you will pay for it later with damage from the humidity.